# Why does my hostname and /etc/hostname get reset on reboot?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, hostname, reboot

I want to change the hostname of my Ubuntu 18 server.

I tried the usual approach of:

- `sudo hostname new_name` - for immediate change
- Editing `/etc/hostname` - for persistent change

Then when I reboot, my hostname has changed back.
Confusingly, the contents of `/etc/hostname` has also changed back.

I've modified other files in `/` and `~`, and those changes survive reboot. So it's not a quirky disk issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Ubuntu 18 it seems you [must do things differently](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-hostname-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux).

`sudo hostnamectl set-hostname new_name`

Also, if `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` exists, edit it to change `preserve_hostname: false` to `true`.